# Reading text file in python which was the output of a Powershell script produces unexpected results?

Tags: python, powershell

I have a `Powershell` script which does many things, and ultimately writes a variable with an integer value to a text file. Below is a simplified example:

```
$theValue = 531231245
$theValue | Out-File .\Test.txt
```

I have also tried to add the `ToString()` method:

```
$theValue = 531231245
$theValue.ToString() | Out-File .\Test.txt
```

It produces a text file, and when I double click on it, there are no surprises. I see `theValue` in both cases in the  text file, clearly as numerical values.

However, I then try to read it in `python` and it produces a strange result

```
with open("Test.txt", 'r') as FID: 
    theText = FID.read()
print(theText)
```

Then the output is:

```
Output : ÿþ5 3 1 2 3 1 2 4 5
```

This is actually the least weird output, as I've received some strange strings that looked like bytes encoding. I tried `decode`, `readlines` and many other things.

I don't understand why I can't properly read the simple string from the text file. Any ideas?

Comment: seems like an encoding issue, try using `Out-File -Encoding utf8 ....` in your powershell script. you don't need the `.ToString()` btw.

Comment: updated answer to strip unicode character ÿþ from the file text. This will work for other encoding issues.

Comment: Can you post the bytes value of the file? `print(open("Test.txt", "rb").read())`.

Comment: on some WIndows shell doesn't use `UTF-8` but different encoding and this can make problem. ie . `latin1`, `cp1250` or somethink different and you may need to use correct `encoding` in `open()` or you may search infrmation how to use `registers` in Windows to set `UTF-8` in shell. ie. [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In *Windows PowerShell*, the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet produces [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)LE ("Unicode") files by default, as does its effective alias, `>`

  - *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, by contrast, fortunately now consistently defaults to BOM-less UTF-8.
- Thus, you have two options:

  - Use `Out-File`'s / [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)'s `-Encoding` parameter to produce a file in the character encoding that Python recognizes by default.
  - Use the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function's `encoding` parameter to match the encoding produced by PowerShell; for *Windows PowerShell*:

    ```
    with open("t.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-16le') as FID: 
      theText = FID.read()
    print(theText)
    ```

Comment: Thanks! I also added the line `theText = theText.strip().encode("ascii", "ignore").decode()` to clean up unicode characters and whitespace